# Unity Question: Transforming world coordinates to my Radar's Coordinates for 3D Radar

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity3D and having some trouble on my 3D radar.  My radar is a child of my Player game object which is rotating around as I fly.  The radar itself is rotated 45 degrees so it faces the user.  There is a Cube that is supposed to be the radar blip of the enemy plane.  The Cube is a child of Radar so should inherit its rotation.  There is a script on the Cube to update itself every update().  Here is the hierarchy:

```
Enemy Plane
Player
-- Camera
-- Radar
------ Cube (radar representation of Enemy Plane)
```

The problem is that while the Cube itself is rotated, with the Radar, its motion is not.  As I get closer to the enemy plane, the Cube just gets closer to the camera (which is good) but I would expect its motion to follow the 45 degree rotation of the parent Radar object?

```
public class RadarGlyph : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject radarSource;
    GameObject trackedObject;
    Vector3 radarScaler;

    void Start()
    {
        this.radarSource = GameObject.Find("Radar");
        this.trackedObject = GameObject.Find("Enemy Fighter");
        this.radarScaler = new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 vDelta = this.trackedObject.transform.position - this.radarSource.transform.position;
        vDelta.Scale(this.radarScaler);
        this.transform.localPosition = this.transform.InverseTransformDirection(vDelta);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how the cube is moving and how it should be moving? It's kind of hard to visualize at the moment.

Comment: If I head straight towards the enemy ship, the cube moves straight at me.  Instead, it should be moving at the slight angle of the radar.  Its like its moving in my space, not using the radars rotation at all, even though the cube is a child of the radar.

Comment: Did one of the two changes I suggested in my answer work?

Comment: Yes, I tried the first one, and it worked beautifully.  But...why?  Why do I have to rotated it by its parent, shouldn't it already be rotated by its parent?

Comment: I edited my answer to include some explanation. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: I think I get that...I'm going to have to digest it a bit.  THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complete solution, you have to get the position of the target wrt the ship first and then recreate it within the context of the blip and the radar.

As a quick fix, you can try changing your last line like this:

```
this.transform.localPosition = this.parent.localRotation * this.transform.InverseTransformDirection(vDelta);
```

or (apparently not good as you mentioned)

```
this.transform.localPosition = Quaternion.Inverse(this.parent.localRotation) * this.transform.InverseTransformDirection(vDelta);
```

one of these is bound to work. (The first one did)

Edit: here's a third alternative

```
this.transform.localPosition = this.transform.parent.parent.InverseTransformDirection(vDelta);
```

This one gets the position in Player's space and applies it in radar's space.

The first and third are trying to do the same thing. **Since you were transforming the direction into the blip's coordinate frame, any rotations that its parents have are canceled out**. Instead, the correct thing to do is to get the position relative to the Player first. Then apply it to the blip in the radar. The third line of code I have here is attempting to do that.